# Log Level Configuration

Tags: nopcommerce

Where can I configure the log level?

In our Plugin, we've got some `logger.Debug("...")` and `logger.Information("...")` but I'm only seeing the `Information` ones [in the Admin site](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/en/Logs).

I assume the fix is changing the log level to `Debug`, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by design it's disabled, thus even if you change the log level from `Information` to `Debug` it won't make any difference, and you won't able see any log at admin area.

To write debug log you have to enable debug log level at `Nop.Services.Logging`> `IsEnabled` rebuild the solution and run it again.

[image]

To implement it with plugin, you would need to override `IsEnabled` method and switch as per user input.

There is an alternate way to write debug log instead:

```
_logger.InsertLog(Nop.Core.Domain.Logging.LogLevel.Debug, "debug info here");
```